# Javascript or Jquery - restricting input field to only 8 decimals

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Is it possible to restrict a form field in HTML with Jquery/Javascript to only 3 decimals . What I mean is that: 33.334 should be allowed as input 3.344 & 444444.556 etc.  as well but it should not allow 5.6664 etc.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need jQuery to do that. Just use `pattern` attribute of `<input>` like this

```
<input type="text" pattern="^\d+\.\d{0,3}$">
```

The above would work on most browsers but if you want to support some old browsers, you would bind that `<input>` on a key-based event and check for the value using the above regex and restricting the user input.

```
$('input').on('blur', function () {
    if (!/^\d+\.\d{0,3}$/.test($(this).val())) {
        alert("Must be a number upto 3 decimals!");
    }
});
```

#### [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/pvkeL23f/2/)

<sub>Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to see `pattern` in action. Click elsewhere to see jQuery in action</sub>

Comment: [According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input) the `pattern` attribute is supported by Chrome 5.0, Firefox 4.0, IE 10, and Opera 9.6. Safari has no support for it. Google reveals [a number of polyfills](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=html5%20input%20pattern%20polyfill) that will let you use the attribute without (much) additional code.